# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_rust_crypto_util_fixed_time_eq_asm" linking with `cc` failed:

Tags: rust, cryptography, linker, rust-crypto

I am working with [rust_crypto](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto) crate to `sign` a text and verify the `signature`. However, I am unable to fix the error that arises while executing this particular code snippet.

**Code Snippet**

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use crypto::ed25519;
    use rand::RngCore;
    use rand::rngs::OsRng;
    #[test]
    fn test_signature() {
        let mut key: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
        OsRng.fill_bytes(&mut key);

        let (secrect_key, public_key) = ed25519::keypair(&key);
        let secret_key = secrect_key.to_vec();
        let public_key = public_key.to_vec();

        let signature = ed25519::signature("test".as_bytes(), &secret_key);
        assert!(ed25519::verify(
            "test".as_bytes(),
            &public_key,
            &signature
        ));
    }
}
```

**Error log**

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
......
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_rust_crypto_util_fixed_time_eq_asm", referenced from:
    crypto::util::fixed_time_eq::had478626f0557b6f in libcrypto-7bb502040bea4c30.rlib(crypto-7bb502040bea4c30.crypto.4149e1f8-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Dependencies**

```
[dependencies]
rust-crypto = "^0.2"
rand = "0.8.5"
```

Is this platform specific? How to solve this?

**Update**

As of this [issue](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/issues/383), `rust-crypto` is no longer maintained.

How to convert repo using `rust-crypto` to [RustCrypto](https://github.com/RustCrypto) as their public, and private key structure changed.

`rust-crypto`

```
let (secrect_key, public_key) = ed25519::keypair(&key)
// `secrect_key` is `[u8;64]` and `public_key` is `[u8;32]`
```

[RustCrypto](https://github.com/RustCrypto)

```
let signing_key = SigningKey::from_seed(&ed25519_seed).unwrap();
let verifying_key = signing_key.verifying_key();
```

To specifically point to the migration I am looking for:

- I previously persisted both the `secrect_key` & `public_key` in local DB (as they are just `[u8]`) and used them for signing, and verifying as needed.
- But, now I don't know what is the persistence strategy for `signing_key`, and `verifying_key` with this new lib.

Comment: Hey Muhtasim Ulfat. Maarten here, mod at [crypto.se] and top contributor for [tag:cryptography]. Some hints for the platform: not getting an answer on a site doesn't mean it is on topic on another. To get more exposure for your question, please make sure you got tags correctly, I'll try and add a few. Finally, I'm glad to see you've had some progress on the issue. If the "Update" is there to hint at an answer, then please use the answer box (although it seems you now have a related question, which should either be in a separate post, or the question should be updated more thoroughly)

Comment: The update I added is not particularly the answer as it is still blocked. I am mostly looking for someone who ported this previously used lib to the newer one while making minimal changes. As the signing, verifying strategy as well as local persistence for those keys have changed, I am very much open to suggestions for migrating from the community before making changes myself. Pointer to any repo that has migrated this change will also help which I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I found the documentation of these libraries so lacking that I'm not willing to sacrifice a lot of time in it. I do see that there are better methods to get a key from existing data than using a seed (that's not some kind of universal way of distributing private keys or key pairs). If you want to have a random key then there are also methods that explicitly use a random. I've answered a lot of questions about crypto in a lot of languages, but I'm kind of horrified what I find if I start looking at Rust, which is really a shame if you consider what the language is for.